# My project uses cookiebot but when I accept cookies at the start of website it deletes my localstorage data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, local-storage, cookiebot

I am working on react project. I have added few localstorage keys which I used for certain functions. So
When the website loads and I accept the cookies it results in deletion of my localstorage data.

I have read docs but couldn't find any possible solutions. I have tried configuring the script but not sure what to do next. I am desperate for help, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.